# Правильно ли построено предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать:

> Детство, не покоренное войной.

Я считаю, что это выражение неправильное.

Comment: Тогда, зачем тратить чернила? Стоит ли обращать внимание на разовые ляпы, если так считаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я тоже считаю такой эпитет неудачным.

Детство - убитое, опалённое, искалеченное, израненное, украденное войной, но покорённое... Война не покоряла детство, а опалила своим огнём, ранила и убивала.

Comment: Я так ждала Вашего ответа, спасибо огромное.

Comment: Спасибо и Вам на добром слове.